# Show that Thomae's Function is Lebesgue Integrable

Tags: lebesgue-integral

I have Thomae's Function defined as follows:

$f(x): [0,1] \to \mathbb R$

$f(x) = q$ if $x$ is rational and $x = p/q$, $0$ otherwise (please note that this is the usual definition of Thomae's function, just with the difference in $q$ and $1/q$

I need to show that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable and compute its integral. I know its value is $0$, however I'm unsure how to start. I think this definition of Thomaes's Function is confusing me, as we are dealing with $q$ and not $1/q$. I found this to be helpful: [Integral of Thomae's function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104782/integral-of-thomaes-function), however it involves Thomaes's Function with $f$ taking on the value $1/q$.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

EDIT: I believe this boils down to showing that the function is zero a.e. (and thus the integral is zero), but again, I'm unsure how to begin.

Comment: You've said that the function is zero for all values except the rationals, isn't that good enough?

Comment: Ah, I think I know: You're saying the set with all the rational points is countable, and all countable sets have measure zero... therefore the function is zero a.e. and hence the integral is 0. Correct?

Comment: Yes, the hard thing would be proving Riemann integrability without knowing about measure.

Comment: Right, because every proof I've seen proving Riemann integrability involves Lebesque integrability criterion. Thanks for the response, it really narrowed down where I needed to look.