# how to check and solve the following riemann integral if function is integrable?

Tags: riemann-integration

let

$$f(x)= \begin{cases}
 x^2  \text{ if $x$ is rational}\\ 
  0 \text{ if $x$ is irrational}
\end{cases}
$$
  let

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{q}  \text{ if $x=\frac{p}{q}$ where $(p,q)=1$}\\
              0   \text{ if $x$ is irrational}
\end{cases}
$$

Then which of the following holds?

a)  $g$ is Riemann integrable but not $f$

b) both $f$ and $g$ Riemann integrable.

c) Riemann integral of $f$ is $0$

d) Riemann integral of $g$ is $0$

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is discontinuous at every point, it follows that its set of discontinuities has a Lebesgue measure $>0$ and so $f$ is not Riemann integrable.

For $g$, note that it is the so called Tomae's function, for which you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) that it is continuous at all irrational numbers and discontinuous at all rationals. Therefore its set of discontinuities is with Lebesgue measure zero and thus it is Riemann integrable. Also its Riemann integral is $0$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1104782/254733))
So (a) and (d)

Comment: thanks a lot. but note that f is continuous at 0 although it has no effect on result.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter. The important thing is that  it is discontinuous everywhere, except at $0$.

Comment: yes @ Svetoslav